# Using templates on Container type in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a generic function to compute barycenter of a bunch of numbers,
I found the following one but I am unable to use it:

```
template <typename Container>
auto getBarycenter(Container &&cont)
{
    decltype(cont[0]) res(0.0f);
    for (auto &v : cont)
        res += v;
    return res / static_cast<float>(cont.size());
}
```

I am new to templates, the data structure I am trying to operate on is `std::vector < cv::Point3f >` (from the OpenCV namespace).

EDIT:

Here is the calls I tried:

```
std::vector<float> vector;

auto value = vector.getBarycenter<std::vector>();
auto value = vector.getBarycenter<std::vector <cv::Point3f> >();
```

Comment: why are you unable to use it? Please include a [mcve] together with the compiler error message in the question

Comment: What's exactly the problem you're facing? Compiler error? Runtime crash? Wrong results?

Comment: Consider using `Container::value_type res{};` instead. And why are you passing in the container as an rvalue reference? Consider using `const Container &cont` instead.

Comment: There's definitely the problem that you try to initialize a reference (`res`) with an rvalue

Comment: It's a forwarding reference, not an rvalue reference.

Comment: `vector.getBarycenter<std::vector>()` is not how you call `getBarycenter`

Comment: You may also want [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the information you provided, there's at least one problem in that snippet showed.

`decltype(cont[0])` evaluates to (potentially non-const) lvalue reference to the containers values. This can be fixed using `std::decay_t` (or `std::remove_cvref`, if you have access to c++20) which will remove the "reference-ness" and constness from the type.

```
template <typename Container>
auto getBarycenter(Container &&cont)
{
    std::decay_t<decltype(cont[0])> res(0.0f);
    for (auto &v : cont)
        res += v;
    return res / static_cast<float>(cont.size());
}
```

Alternatively, as mentioned by @Remy Lebeau  you can use `value_type` if you're using std containers:

```
typename std::decay_t<Container>::value_type res(0.0f);
```

Also you should probably better default initialize `res` rather than use a float literal.

Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vnG1nG).